# vb.net passing a value of text box to a variable

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim SecondName As String = SecondNameTxtBox.text()
```

Is the above statement a correct one?

Here I want to assign the value of the text box into tat "SecondName".
If it's wrong, please tell me the correct way to write this statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not correct.  `SecondNameTxtBox.Text` is a property, not a method, so leave off the parentheses.

Comment: +1 One of the annoyances of VB.NET that it does not enforce coding style.

Comment: Dim SecondName As String = SecondNameTxtBox.text

so u mean tat this s correct